# Writing data to a NTFS partition while Windows 7 is hibernating

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, windows-8, filesystems, hibernate

According to this [MountingWindowsPartitions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MountingWindowsPartitions) if you write from linux to a NTFS partition while Windows 7 is hibernating, when Windows 7 awakes all changes are lost. The justification is:

> when Windows 7 is hibernated it writes the system state to a file
>   stored on disk and restores from that file when the system is
>   re-awakened, thus restoring the whole fileystem to a state before any
>   changes made from Ubuntu

I haven't try this, but I find it really hard to believe. I know that it saves the system state to the hibernation file and that when it awakes it restores that state. But as far as I know (and I am pretty sure I know this right) this is all about system memory (RAM + swap), not storage (hard-disk). How could Windows possibly save the whole HDD state (lets's say a few terabits) or know what modifications were done to it in order to restore it (and undo the changes to it). This doesn't make any sense. If the article was a random page on the internet I would have just ignored it, but this is the official Ubuntu documentation, so I have to consider I am missing or misinterpreting something.

I can imagine how there could be problems if Windows had a file opened in exclusive mode and it is modified while it is hibernating, but that is a different matter.

My main interest here is academic (I am a CS student), but also a practical one as 
I am switching to a dual boot configuration (Ubuntu and Windows7/Windows8 (haven't decived yet)) with shared NTFS partitions.

Comment: a simple analogy… the postman tries to deliver a big parcel while you're still asleep… does it arrive if you don't hear the doorbell, trudge down 3 flights of stairs, open the door, take the parcel, sign for it … NO.

Comment: I think that you've missed the point. Windows will restore the filesystem in its original sate. That said, it means that all pointers to the files that doesn't existed at the moment of hibernation will be erased. When you delete files, you are not removing the actual data but pointers for these files from the filesystem table. When Windows 7 restore filesystem table after hibernation, you will not be able to access the files you saved from Ubuntu during the Win 7 hibernation period.
Hibernation doesnt snapshot HDD w/ data

Comment: @Tetsujin yes, if my brother Ubuntu signes for it

Comment: postman won't give ubuntu the parcel, as he doesn't look like the picture on windows' ID card. Windows is asleep. Either Windows wakes up & comes to get his parcel, or the postman takes it away with him.

Comment: or… you cannot hammer an inscription on a stone… when all you have is a photograph of the stone.

Comment: @Tetsujin the data is written to the hard disk. While windows is hibernating Ubuntu has access to the HDD and the data is phisically written to the hard disk. Windows doesn't have to wake for the writes to be be accepted by the hard disk. The issue is when Windows wakes. Then it restores (acording to the article and to Nikola), but the data has already been accepted and written.

Comment: it restores what it went to sleep with. there is nothing you can do to write to that hiberfile. The machine is dead to the world for that period. I'm surprised your own machine would even think it could connect to it at that time; it ought to return nothing but a timeout.

Comment: @NikolaDimitrijevic does it do this only for the system partition (`C:`) or for all the partitions? Does it do it for external drives also?

Comment: @Tetsujin Actually, the postman will deliver the package and will leave the receipt, and the package will be there. But after Windows wake up he will not be aware of the package and the receipt and both will end up in the garbage :) 

bolov - Yes exactly, Ubuntu will write the data in NTFS system physically, just the information where the new data resides will be lost after waking up from hibernation. If you use some recovery program that can read data on low level, you will see that actual data written by Ubuntu are there, just NTFS pinters to that data doesn't exists anymore

Comment: If normally installed it will do that just for the system partition. But if installed unconventionally, it will do that for all partitions with system files. If you installed your system in C and D partition (it is possible) it will do that for C and D

Comment: @NikolaDimitrijevic I guess we're stretching the analogy too far, but yes; the postman drops a card through the letterbox… you then have to go to the post office to find out what it was that you missed. If the card is not noticed, the parcel is never collected.

Comment: @Tetsujin well, you can say it that way... the package will still exists in the post office :)

Comment: but you don't know it's there. We are now going round in circles. The hiberfile cannot be written to whilst the machine is not running, so how can it even discover is has a 'parcel to collect'?

Comment: @Tetsujin the hibernation file doesn't have to be written. All windows has to do to be aware of the changes is read the MFT of the NTFS drive.

Comment: You cannot be aware of anything when you're asleep. [but we're going round in circles, I'm out]

Comment: @Tetsujin I meant when he wakes

Comment: @Tetsjuin  at one moment I thought that you have figured out. After waking up, Win will RESTORE the filesystem to exact state at the moment of hibernation, meaning that it will erase the NTFS pointers to any additional files. It doesn't matter who is aware of what. If the file exists and you detach that HDD and attach it to another Windows or Linux computer (before waking up) you will be able to read that files, as NTFS file table will have the info about the new files. 
Here the issue is not Windows, but the point is that Ubuntu will not be able to read data after Win wake up